# Как нарисовать линию при выборе двух точек?

Tags: jquery, canvas, html, javascript

Доброго все времени суток! Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при выборе двух точек между ними рисовалась линия. То есть, к примеру, есть нарисованная карта с городами. Выбираешь один город, потом второй, и после этого между ними появляется прямая линия, якобы маршрут. Вот скрин примера:

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

Например, с помощью [JSGraphics](http://www.karlson.ru/jsgraphics/html/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <canvas />

<script language="JavaScript">
    var mouse = {
        x: -1,
        y: -1
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var cvs = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
        $("canvas").click(function(e){
            if(mouse.x != -1 && mouse.y != -1){
                cvs.beginPath();
                cvs.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                cvs.lineTo(e.pageX, e.pageY);
                cvs.closePath();
                cvs.stroke();
                mouse.x = -1;
                mouse.y = -1;
            }else{
                mouse.x = e.pageX;
                mouse.y = e.pageY;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как поменять цвет и толщину линии?? и как сделать чтобы рисовать можно было не где угодно, а именно там где стоят точки городов, то есть если выбраны именно города а не просто на любом месте нажато.

Comment: определять координаты, если они попадают в e.pageX,e.pageY то тогда присваивать данные для mouse если нет то соответсвенно ничего не делать. Это же пальцем в небо тыкаю сейчас. Если имеете карту в SVG там еще проще все организовать.

Comment: Не это просто картинка с точками!